# is eigenvector 1 dimensional subspace of vector V?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was taking a course on linear algebra where it was first said that "one dimension subspace" containing a vector $v$ is a same line which is formed by multiplying it by any scalar $s$. So, any vector on this line is subspace that contains $v$

When I learned about eigenvectors, it says that when $v$ is multiplied by an eigenvector, it only "scales".

So, my question is,  is eigenvector same as 1d subspace of $v$? (eigenvector of $v$ == 1d subspace of $v$)?

(This question might have been answered on internet elsewhere but may be I am not using right words and my understanding is not very good to formalize the question)

Comment: The entire question is very flawed. A vector cannot be a subspace. A subspace is a set of vectors. In this state, is is hard to answer the question, because it is not clear what you have understood (or not) so far...

Comment: @MushuNrek yes I am afraid that I am not able to put it into words, it it right to say "Does eigenvector always result in transformation that is in subspace containing V"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "eigenvector of $V$" doesn't quite make sense. Eigenvectors only make sense when associated with linear transformations. An eigenvector $v$ of a linear transformation $T$ is a vector with the property that $T(v) = \lambda v$, for some scalar $\lambda$.

That being said, for some eigenvector $v$ of a linear transformation $T$, the space spanned by $v$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace (but the fact that $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ is completely irrelevant). We are often more interested in the $\lambda$-eigenspaces of a transformation $T$, which is the space of all vectors $v$ such that $T(v) = \lambda v$. The $\lambda$-eigenspaces of a transformation can, but need not be, one dimensional (in which case there is only one linearly independent eigenvector).

Comment: thanyou for the answer. I think I have got the idea, just to clear, "the space spanned by v is a 1-dimensional subspace of what(vector V?)

Comment: Or let me rephrase, does this "1-demensioanl subspace" contain the vector `V`? (i think I am still not able to form the question, I give up)

Comment: If $T$ is a linear transformation from vectors spaces $V \to W$, then the space spanned by an eigenvector $v$ of $T$ is a *one-dimensional subspace of $V$*. The one-dimensional subspace contains $v$ and all of its scalar multiples.

Comment: Got it thankyou.

Comment: Sorry in my previous comment, $W$ should be replaced with $V$. Eigenvectors only make sense if the transformation is a map from the domain to itself (i.e. an endomorphism).